# click function only works on my first item in my repeater, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom-traversal

Here is my markup:

```
 <a href="#" id="buyMobileTickets" class="btn blue" data-ivaid="<%# ((MovieModel)Container.DataItem).FID %>">Buy Ticket(s)</a>
```

here is the jquery in documentReady

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#buyMobileTickets").on("click", mobileTickets);
});
```

here is my function:

```
 function mobileTickets(e, ui) {      
        var ivaId = $(this).attr("data-ivaid");
        var theatre = Regal.userPrimaryTheatre;
        var movietDt = new Date();

        window.open("http://www.fandango.com/redirect.aspx?&a=12878&dte=0&mid=" + ivaId + "&tid=" + theatre , "_blank");

    }
```

This works only for the first data element in my repeater, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does all your Items have same `ID`

Comment: IDs are *unique*.  There should only be *one* `#buyMobileTickets` element.

Answer (score 6):

Because there should be no elements with the same ID in HTML. There can always be one element with a specific ID in a document.

You should use a class instead:

```
<a href="#" class="buyMobileTickets btn blue" ...>Buy Ticket(s)</a>
```

and then the class selector with jQuery:

```
$(".buyMobileTickets").on("click", mobileTickets);
```

Comment: great, how do I formulate this line with a class <a href="#" id="buyMobileTickets" class="btn blue" data-ivaid="<%# ((MovieModel)Container.DataItem).FID %>">Buy Ticket(s)</a>

Comment: @PaulT.Rykiel Updated my answer with an example.

Comment: @PaulT.Rykiel: You already have a class in that line.  Just add another.